# Kill command in UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

If I execute the Following command all the process will be killed and the account
is logged out.

Command:

```
kill -9 -1
```

It is similar to the logout command. In Unix, no such process having the pid as "-1". So, what is the reason for this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the manual page (http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill)

> If pid equals -1, then sig is sent to every process for which the
>   calling process has permission to send signals, except for process 1
>   (init), but see below.

So I guess that is you out of the system - but life continues for the rest of us

PS: It is not graceful

Answer (score 2):

When the pid argument of `kill` is prefixed with a `-`, it sends the signal to the process group instead. Every process has a pid, but also a process group id.

You can see this by running this:

```
$ bash -c 'sleep 10 & sleep 1; ps -o pid,ppid,pgrp,cmd'
  PID  PPID  PGRP CMD
22471 22467 22471 -bash
22496 22471 22496 bash -c sleep 10 & sleep 1; ps -o pid,ppid,pgrp,cmd
22497 22496 22496 sleep 10
22499 22496 22496 ps -o pid,ppid,pgrp,cmd
```

Here you can see the `bash -c` has gotten its own process group (22496, same as its PID), and its two child processes (sleep and ps), has inherited this process group.

`kill -TERM 22496` would send a TERM signal to the `bash -c` process with pid 22496, while `kill -TERM -22496` would send a TERM signal to the three processes `bash -c`, `sleep` and `ps`.

`-1` however, is a special case, that sends the signal to all processes you can send to.

Answer (score -1):

kill -9 -1 eliminates the need to hard reboot the system and is mainly useful to efficiently and cleanly terminate programs that have are not responding.

Comment: the syntax of kill command is "kill <SIGNAL> <PID>". Here signal is optional. So, what is -1 stands for.

Comment: `kill -9` is not a clean way of ending a process. I is harsh